# Cannot enlarge figures beyond fig.height=12, fig.width=10 with rmarkdown::render() to html

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr

I cannot enlarge the figures beyond fig.height=12, fig.width=10: in the resulting html page, figures get the same size, letters and symbols become smaller. I've put an Rmd as example here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a3x95n1iviffhs/tmaptest2_log.Rmd?dl=1

which I process with

```
rmarkdown::render("tmaptest2_log.Rmd", html_document(toc=TRUE,toc_float = TRUE, code_folding = "hide", keep_md = TRUE))
```